# Sturm-liouville problem, first eigenvalue

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Any idea to solve the Sturm-Liouville Problem 
$$
-\cos^{2}(t)g''+n\sin(t)\cos(t)g'-(n+1)\cos^{2}(t)g=(\delta)g,
$$
with $t\in[\epsilon,0]$, and boundary conditions $g(\epsilon)=g(0)=0$?

We may rewrite the equation as

$$
(\cos^{n}(t)g')'+(n+1)\cos^{n}(t)g+(\delta)\cos^{n-2}(t)g=0.
$$

I wanna know the first eigenvalue.

Thanks!

Comment: Is $\delta$ a constant? is it sign indefinite?